# protected / private variable types - check task

Tags: python, variables, inheritance

below is the content of the task, I wanted to make sure if I did this sentence correctly, because the method call returns two the same results, I do not know if this was the point (?), Can I ask you to check the code if it is correctly executed?

- Define a variable protect the class id Person and a private variable
  age. Check with dir () to see how the variables were created in the
  class structure.

code:

```
class Person:
   _id = "120"
   __age = "12"

   print(dir(_id))
   print(dir(__age))
```

Comment: both id and age are a string so calling dir on each of them will just tell you all about what strings can do. you want to call dir on the person class outside of the class

Comment: one underscore is protected and double underscore is private attribute

Comment: I agree with @ChrisDoyle - I think the question is asking you to perform `dir` on the class.

Comment: ie the command dir () should be called on the Person class?

Answer (score 1):

as i said in my comment, Dir tells you about an object, both `_id` and `__age` are both string objects, Since they are both string objects you get the same output. Instead you should call dir on the person class like

```py
class Person:
   _id = "120"
   __age = "12"

print(dir(Person))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['_Person__age', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_id']
```

The key points to note about the attributes are

```
'_Person__age'
'_id'
```

you see the double under score name mangles the attribute.